# PHP script to extract emails based on domains from toggle list

Tags: php, list, email, dns, toggle

I've searched and searched and cannot find anything similar (or at least what I  consider similar or can get my head around).
I'm not very great with coding, so I was hoping someone could help me further my script so far.

```php
<?php
$str3 = array(
    'START@EMAIL.COM',
    /* List of emails below to be scanned must be 'user@provider.com', exactly that like
    /* emails here to be loaded in from rmcomputers/council 'END@EMAIL.COM');
    /* Filter code below*/
    foreach($str3 as $new)
        {
        /*List of domains to filter and show */
        if (strpos($new, 'teacher.establishment1.sch.uk') !== false || strpos($new, 'teacher.establishment2.sch.uk') !== false || strpos($new, 'teacher.establishment3.sch.uk') !== false || strpos($new, 'teacher.establishment4.sch.uk') !== falsestrpos($new, 'teacher.establishment5.sch.uk') !== false)
            {
            echo "$new" . " <a href=' $new'> $new</a></br>";
            }
        }
?>
```

https://pastebin.com/raw/HRdzDJq1

I am looking to improve this script, so I don't need to manually edit the domains every so often depending on what I'm looking for.

I will have around 150 "domains" on the list - I'd like to be able to toggle off/on depending on the search I need to do.

The code on the pastebin currently when I've loaded my full list of emails into it outputs only the users as I wish, but if I need to output another establishment/domain then I need to edit the code and add/remove domains as required.

You'll probably get the gist of what I'd like to have done eventually.
At the moment I edit the .php file and load it when needed, but this is becoming a nuisance.

**Mockup of script**

[image: Mockup of script]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the domains via `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables, separated by comma `,` and then loop it after `explode()`.

So you page call would be `index.php?domains=domain1.com,domain2.com`, also you can do it through a form...

Your `PHP` logic will looks like below:

```
$domains = explode(',', $_GET['domains']);

/* Filter code below*/

foreach ($str3 as $new) {
    foreach( $domains as $domain){ //Loop the domains
        if (strpos($new, $domain) !== false){
            echo "$new" . "  <a href=' $new'> $new</a></br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But remember that there is a limit on the length of the URL, which includes all parameters if you use GET. So if you have too many domains, you may wish to use POST right away.

Comment: Cheers for this, I'll give it a go, still searching for alternative to see if there is existing scripts available